# Loading a 3D Array from a VarLenDeature in TfRecords with Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load 3D Arrays from TFRecord Data into Tensorflow.
The Data has not been created by me and I have just been given the image_feature_description Dictionary.
But I am not sure if what I am doing is correct and in doesn't seem right.

```
def read_tf_tens(path, file=None):
    print("Inside read_tf_tens")
    print(path)
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)
    print("jup")
    image_feature_description = {
        'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
        'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
        'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
        'spacing': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32, default_value=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
        'origin': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32, default_value=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
        'mask': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        'image': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
    }
    #@tf.function
    def _parse_image_function(proto):
        return tf.io.parse_single_example(proto, image_feature_description)

    parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

    #These were needed, because Tensorflow else told be that The Varibles needed to be initialized      
    height = np.int64(256)
    width = np.int64(256)
    depth = np.int64(709)
    spacing = np.float32(256)
    origin = np.float32(256)
    mask = np.zeros((depth,height,width),dtype=np.int64)
    image = np.zeros((depth,height,width),dtype=np.float32)


    for image_features in parsed_dataset:
        height = image_features['height']
        width = image_features['width']
        depth = image_features['depth']
        spacing = image_features['spacing']
        origin = image_features['origin']
        mask = image_features['mask'].values
        image = image_features['image'].values

    shape = (depth[0] , width[0], height[0])
    print(shape)
    image_array = tf.reshape(image,shape)
    print(image_array)
    mask_array = tf.reshape(mask, shape)
    print(mask_array.shape)
    return image_array, mask_array, shape, spacing, origin
```

Here is the output:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_2:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>)
Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(None, None, None), dtype=float32)
(None, None, None)
```

This is what happens if I print my Dataset in total(With it Containing the Contents of the Array and a Integer Label.

```
Sets:  [<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((None, None, None), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>]
```

Now the Shape (None,None,None) is making me worried. this doesn't seem right.
Can anybody help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

So here is a weird one. apparently loading in the numpy value and then reshaping it in a tensor is dong the trick for me.

```
def read_tf_tens(path, file):
read_file = path + '/' + file
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(read_file)

image_feature_description = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'spacing': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32, default_value=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
    'origin': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.float32, default_value=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
    'mask': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    'image': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
}

def _parse_image_function(proto):
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(proto, image_feature_description)

parsed_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

for image_features in parsed_dataset:
    height = image_features['height'].numpy()
    width = image_features['width'].numpy()
    depth = image_features['depth'].numpy()
    spacing = image_features['spacing'].numpy()
    origin = image_features['origin'].numpy()
    mask = image_features['mask'].values.numpy()
    image = image_features['image'].values.numpy()

shape = (depth[0], width[0], height[0]) # without data augmentation
#image_array = np.reshape(image, shape)
#mask_array = np.reshape(mask, shape)
image_array = tf.keras.backend.reshape(image, shape)
mask_array = tf.keras.backend.reshape(mask, shape)

return image_array, mask_array, shape, spacing, origin
```